# How do I avoid catastrophic cancellation for small numbers in f(x) = (1-cos(x))/x**2 in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, trigonometry, floating-accuracy

How do I avoid catastrophic cancellation for small numbers in
f(x) = (1-cos(x))/x**2 in Python 3.7?

This is what I tried so far (the key, I know, is some trigonometric identity that enables you to avoid the cancellation, and I also know, having used L'Hopital's rule, that the limit→0 for f(x) is 0.5, so the correct program output is something very close to 0.5, which is what you do get if you use x = 1.2e-4 for example, but you get cancellation with smaller numbers like 1.2e-8, and I need to make it so this doesn't happen).

```
from math import *
def f(x):     #these are all the same function using different identities  
   a = (1-(sin(x)/tan(x)))/(x**2)
   b = (1-(sin(2*x)/(2*sin(x))))/(x**2)
   c = (1-((1-((tan(x/2))**2))/(1+(tan(x/2))**2)))/(x**2)
   d = (sin(x)**2+cos(x)**2-cos(x))/(x**2)
   e = (sin(x)**2+cos(x)**2-(sin(2*x)/(2*sin(x))))/(x**2)
   return a, b, c, d, e

print(k(1.2e-8))
#Output: (0.0, 0.7709882115452477, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) - whereas need 0.5000...
```

Comment: you could consider using `numpy` which has 64bit `float64`. That may help with the cancellations.

Comment: There is another identity: sin(x)/tan(x) = cos(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
sin(x)/x * tan(x/2)/x
```

It does the job right up to the end, `x = 1e-308` is still OK.

Unfortunately I cannot offer much insight into *why* it works well.

Comment: Probably has to do with implementation of `sin` vs `cosine`. Note that `sin(1e-100)=1e-100` while `cos(1e-100)=1.0`. Similarly, `tan(1e-100)=1e-100`.

Comment: I'm guessing they used the approximation `sin(x)=x` when `x` is small. You can show using L'Hopital that `sin(x)/x` approaches 1 when `x` approaches 0

Comment: You can replace sin(x)/x by numpy.sinc(x/numpy.pi) - sinc has the limit 1 as x approaches 0. Tan(x)/x can also be expressed using sinc

Comment: Perfect! This is amazing, thanks a lot @harold and Tim and Stefan. Your inputs are very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Use Herbie! https://herbie.uwplse.org/demo/2909ec7f21a1b11ab3f8f89a6cfb9af1d6908f5b.494956fc14c21e1eb91b1bc1760ad668a0f02cb8/graph.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.float128` instead. `numpy` is the standard for data analysis and more complex math. It can be installed with the following command in the terminal.

```
pip install numpy
```

```
from numpy import *
def f(x):     #these are all the same function using different identities  
   a = (1-(sin(x)/tan(x)))/(x**2)
   b = (1-(sin(2*x)/(2*sin(x))))/(x**2)
   c = (1-((1-((tan(x/2))**2))/(1+(tan(x/2))**2)))/(x**2)
   d = (sin(x)**2+cos(x)**2-cos(x))/(x**2)
   e = (sin(x)**2+cos(x)**2-(sin(2*x)/(2*sin(x))))/(x**2)
   return a, b, c, d, e
print(f(float128(1.2e-8)))
```

This prints

```
(0.5003141275115400736, 0.49956120933620291774, 0.49993766842387149567, 0.49993766842387149567, 0.49956120933620291774)
```

Comment: float128 is equivalent to float64 on some platforms

Comment: changed `numpy.float128` to `float128`, since we still want to use the `numpy` versions of the trig functions.

Comment: float64 unfortunately doesn't work, so may have to defer to @harold's answer if your platform defaults float128 to float64

Answer (score 2):

> How do I avoid catastrophic cancellation for small numbers in f(x) = (1-cos(x))/x**2 in Python 3.7?

You can use a half-angle identity:

1 − cos(x) = 2 sin²(x/2).

(Historical trigonometers will recognize this as the versine function, or twice the haversine function, which is useful and tabulated for this purpose!)

If you compute `cos(x)` as an approximation to cos(x) for x near 0, then catastrophic cancellation in the subtraction 1 − `cos(x)` may dramatically amplify any error in that approximation—possibly giving a nonsense answer, if `cos(x)` is rounded to 1 so `(1 - cos(x))/x**2` is rounded to 0 when it should be near 1/2.

In contrast, if you rewrite it as

(1 − cos(x))/x² = 2 sin²(x/2)/x²

using the half-angle identity, and then evaluate `2*(sin(x/2)/x)**2` for x near zero, you are composing functions on domains where they are well-conditioned.
In binary floating-point, dividing and multiplying by two is always exact except in case of overflow or underflow, and sin and squaring are both well-conditioned near zero, so the relative error is reasonably small even with intermediate rounding and error in the math library's `sin` procedure.

You can also use another half-angle identity,

1 − cos(x) = sin(x) tan(x/2),

as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66300127) suggests—both sin and tan are well-conditioned near zero, so it will also give a good approximation.
But it costs more to compute sin and tan than to just compute sin, and I see no obvious advantage in error at least for inputs near zero.

To handle x = 0 without conditionals, if you have a `sinc` procedure which approximates the function sinc(x) = sin(x)/x naturally extended with the limit sinc(0) = 0, you could also rewrite it as:

(1 − cos(x))/x² = 2 sin²(x/2)/x² = (1/2) sin²(x/2)/(x/2)² = (1/2) sinc²(x/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally return the limit for small x, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
epsilon=1e-8

def f(x):
   if x<epsilon
      return 0.5

   return (1-sin(x)/tan(x))/x**2
   #note: same as (1-cos(x))/x**2

x=arange(0,6,0.01)
y=vectorize(f)
plt.plot(x,y(x))
plt.show()
```

The curve plotted looks smooth

Note: I prefer numpy to math. Vectorize makes it possible to call the function with an array (not very efficient, but it is easy to use).

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is the limited precision of float and double. You have to use arithmetic with more precision such as mpfr. It can be used in Python through binding such as

https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/

Here is an example where I'm using it through a more high level environment called Sagemath: I'm using 100 bits of precision:

```py
sage: R = RealField(100)  // 100 bits of precision
sage: def f(x):     #these are all the same function using different identities  
....:    a = (1-(sin(x)/tan(x)))/(x**2)
....:    b = (1-(sin(2*x)/(2*sin(x))))/(x**2)
....:    c = (1-((1-((tan(x/2))**2))/(1+(tan(x/2))**2)))/(x**2)
....:    d = (sin(x)**2+cos(x)**2-cos(x))/(x**2)
....:    e = (sin(x)**2+cos(x)**2-(sin(2*x)/(2*sin(x))))/(x**2)
....:    return a, b, c, d, e
....: 
sage: f(R(1.2e-8))
(0.50000000000000264647624775223,
 0.49999999999999716827551705076,
 0.49999999999999716827551705076,
 0.49999999999999716827551705076,
 0.49999999999999169007478634929)
```

Comment: It's polite to say what is the problem when downvote !

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! (I didn't downvote it, upvoted)

Comment: “Use more precision” is not a general good answer for floating-point. One should understand the issues. [William Kahan credits the following example to Jean-Michel Muller around 1980.](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Mindless.pdf) Let f(y, z) = 108−(815−1500/z)/y. Given x[0] = 4 and x[1] = 4¼, define x[n+1] = f(x[n], x[n-1]). Compute x[80]. The correct answer is near 5. All numerical implementations get it wrong; most report 100. See the linked paper for why. A good answer for OP’s question is to understand the sources of error and design a calculation that avoids or reduces them.

Comment: To be clear, an implication of “All numerical implementations get it wrong” is that using more bits will not help. Using arithmetic with more precision will not get the right answer. This example was of course crafted for that, and using more precision will often help routine calculations. But sometimes it just kicks the can farther down the road.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Thanks for the pointer. I tried you counter example with 1000 bits of precision and got 4.99999999999999999785572107704779534792177... So it's more complicated than that. While I agree with you on the principle, I assumed the question to be an implementation question and not a math / numerical analysis question which would be out of scope on SO.

Comment: Math and numerical analysis are not out of scope on Stack Overflow, at least not *per se*, although questions in almost any area can end up being too broad to answer. Certainly if concise answers are possible, math and numerical analysis as they are applicable to programming are in scope. (Do people have some idea that programming is just coding? Computer science is about computers the way astronomy is about telescopes.) And the question asks to avoid catastrophic cancellation and particularly mentions using a trigonometric identity to avoid it.